# Does S3 encrypt data in transit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am trying to move potentially sensitive data to an S3 bucket from where I can put it into an Amazon Redshift cluster to perform analytics. I am transferring data from our current MySQL tables to CSVs, uploading them to S3, and using COPY to put the data into Redshift.  I have attempted to use client side encryption using boto3 in Python, however it has not been successful.  I read that S3 uses TLS encryption in transit when uploading files to S3.  Can anyone confirm this?  Could I rely on that and not have to worry about using client side encryption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The AWS API is a REST service that supports SSL/TLS connections. All the official AWS SDKs and CLI tools connect to the AWS API via SSL/TLS by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, does this mean I can rely on the TLS connection instead of having to worry about client side encryption?

Comment: You can certainly rely on the TLS connection to encrypt the data in transit. It's up to you to decide if that meets your business requirements or not.

Comment: Sorry for the continued questions, but when you say it connects via TLS by default, that process is handled entirely on its own?  There is no setup I need to do or certificate I need to have?  Essentially, when I upload a file to S3 using boto3 I don't have to worry about specifying TLS, it will automatically use it because the SDK knows to?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is a REST service. So you may simply use SSL to protect the data in transit if you are using the S3 API or use client side encryption if you are using the AWS SDK.